# H.264 encode with B-frames frame count

Tags: h.264

Suppose i encode three YUV frames using simple H.264 and get a framepattern IPIP

But then allowing B-frames in encoding I get IBPBIPBP.....

These are clearly more frames than the simple one so do we play these frames at a higher rate to get original three frames?

In other words how is this related to actual time?

Comment: There is something wrong with your assumptions. Frame counts are independent from frame ordering. 3 frames is 3 frames. There are no magic hidden frames. (Expect in vp9/av1)

Answer (score 0):

Coders generate B frames (if they have the capability) not to play tricks with the frame rate, but to encode those frames with fewer bits in the channel, or to get higher quality for the same channel bitrate than just IPPPPIPPPP.